# How to get data from json url

Tags: jquery, json

I would like to display data (country name and money value) from the https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json to my web page. Please suggest me a way to do so.

Comment: first problem is, you are doing cross-domain. then, the data doesn't look like JSONP. This won't go anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSONP for making such requests, but i think the url you are trying to access does not have JSONP feature. Since you want the exchange rates (i guess as per the url you are trying to use), you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://openexchangerates.org/latest.json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            // Rates are in `json.rates`
            // Base currency (USD) is `json.base`
            // UNIX Timestamp when rates were collected is in `json.timestamp`        

            rates = json.rates;
            base = json.base;
            console.log(rates);
        }
    });
});
```

Ref: [See Here](http://josscrowcroft.github.com/open-exchange-rates/#javascript-ajax-jquery)

Hope it helps

Comment: why the dataType is 'jsonp' instead of 'json' ?

Answer (score 3):

This should work with [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //the variable 'data' will have the JSON object
    // In your example, the following will work:
    alert(data.disclaimer);
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     //Error handling code
     alert('Oops there was an error');
   }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery.getJSON() function

go through this tutorial http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: getJSON will not work out-of-the-box for OP's situation because it most probably is a cross-domain request (unless OP is working at GitHub :) ). You need to append a 'callback=?' to the URL to make getJSON work. In any case, I would recommend using $.ajax as best practice so that errors can be handled gracefully.

Comment: $.getJson()  is a shorthand Ajax function refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Yes, I know it is a short hand for $.ajax. But in this particular situation, unless you add '&callback=?' to the URL when calling getJSON, it will not work since OP is making a cross-domain call.